# Box blur effect on texture (soften edges)

Tags: java, graphics, image-processing, qr-code

How to soften edges of texture, 'rounding' it? The actual problem is to soften edges of QR code width width n pixels, like [here](http://blog.justscan.it/2011/10/bar-code-design-soften-edges-in-qr-code.html). I need some simple algorithm without heavy calculations, or at least some ready made libraries in Java/C++.

[image][image]